# NSString stringWithContentsOfURL encoding Problem

Tags: iphone

my app downloads and parses an xml file that contains German Umlauts (ä, ö, ü) and other special character (&, % etc). I seem to have a generall lack of understanding when it comes to encoding issues.

so what i do at the moment is:

1. try to locate if i allready cached the xml file in my apps documents folder

1.a if the file exists i load it into a string

```
NSString * xmlData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filenameStr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

1.b if the file doesn't exist download its contents and save it afterwards

```
NSString *xmlData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlRequest encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
[xmlData writeToFile: filenameStr atomically: FALSE encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]
```

3. afterwards (the data is loaded now) i want to parse it...

however, the contents of the xmlData is already "wrong" after stringWithContentsofURL returns (as i see it in the debugger). Also if i open the file that i saved into my documents folder, it's wrong too.

any advice, links, tips or best practices regarding encoding will be appreciated

thanks

sam

Comment: Can you confirm that the XML file on the server is actually UTF8-encoded and the server delivers it as such?

Comment: As Ole suggests ensure the source is correctly encoded and delivered. For the latter, you could try using a web proxy such as Charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and check the Content-Type & Content-Encoding HTTP headers to see if they really are UTF-8?

Comment: hi there, thx for your comments.. I just double checked it, it indeed is UTF-8. I found out that the my parser had some issues. I'm able to see the umlauts now, but still have some problems displaying '&' which is a a bit strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the encoding of the xml and use it when initializing the string (see details [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-DontLinkElementID_5))

And because of

> I seem to have a generall lack of understanding when it comes to encoding issues.

look [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 0):

the file is not wrong its the encoding issue,

actually when contents are in some other language it is rendered in encoded form.

refer this question for help

[xml parsing problem in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041238/xml-parsing-problem-in-iphone)